# check if pandas series contains a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to check if there is a cell with type dict in pandas series.

My pandas series looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([{'a':'1'}, np.nan, {'b':'2'}, np.nan], name="s")
```

I'd like to basically check if there is at least `1` dict in the series and evaluate a condition.

```
if `dict` in series:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a series:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([{'a':'1'}, np.nan, {'b':'2'}, np.nan], name="s")
>>> s.apply(type).eq(dict).any()
True

>>> s2 = pd.Series([['a', '1'], np.nan, ['b', '2'], np.nan], name="s2")
>>> s2.apply(type).eq(dict).any()
False
```

For a column of a DataFrame:

```py
>>> df = pd.concat([s, s2], axis=1)
>>> df['s'].apply(type).eq(dict).any()
True

>>> df['s2'].apply(type).eq(dict).any()
False
```

---

```
>>> if s.apply(type).eq(dict).any():
...     print('True!')
...
True!
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible:

```
>>> s.explode().apply(type).eq(dict).groupby(level=0).max()
s    True
dtype: bool

>>> s.apply(lambda x: max(isinstance(i, dict) for i in x))
s    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: how would you apply this to a pandas dataframe column `df['col']` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right because `df['col']` is a `Series`

Comment: Hmm, I getting `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: I suppose you have some rows with `NaN` instead of `list`?

Comment: yes, there are rows with `NaN`, sorry thought I was demonstrating with `np.nan`

Comment: A workaround: `s.dropna().apply(lambda x: max(isinstance(i, dict) for i in x)).reindex(s.index, fill_value=False)`

Comment: Another workaround: `s.apply(lambda x: max(isinstance(i, dict) for i in x) if isinstance(x, list) else False)`

Comment: this prints a list of True / False values, I need to evaluate a condition.

Comment: Which condition?

Comment: if series contains a `dict` == True:

Comment: You already have the result. If True the series (the row?) contains a dict. Maybe you can update your post with a more detailed example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246290/discussion-between-kms-and-corralien).